# Plotting multiple bar graphs in dynamic Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe 'grid' that looks like this:

```
COLUMN_NM    DISTINCT_COUNT    MAX_COL_VALUE    MIN_COL_VALUE   NULL_COUNT
COL_A         123                 456                111              56
COL_B         15678               222                4                 3456
COL_C         18994               456                76               43               
...
```

The data in COLUMN_NM is dynamic as this DataFrame gets loaded with different tables for analysis. What I want to do is graph the current data that resides in the DataFrame.  I want a bar graph for DISTINCT_COUNT another for MAX_COL_VALUE etc...all per column.  So the COLUMN_NM would be represented along the x-axis

What I have so far is incorrect clearly, but you get some idea of what I am trying to do.

```
distinct = grid[('COLUMN_NM', 'DISTINCT_COUNT')].plot(kind=bar)
max_col = grid[('COLUMN_NM', 'MAX_COL_VALUE')].plot(kind=bar)
min_col = grid[('COLUMN_NM', 'MIN_COL_VALUE')].plot(kind=bar)
null_cnt = grid[('COLUMN_NM', 'NULL_COUNT')].plot(kind=bar)
```

I have all the necessary import statements. I want the output to be 4 graphs, and I can specify more bar chart parameters after I get this working.  Also, would it be easier to wrap this in a for loop, or function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'd recommend doing this in a loop:

```
for col in ['DISTINCT_COUNT', 'MAX_COL_VALUE', 'MIN_COL_VALUE', 'NULL_COUNT']:
    grid[['COLUMN_NM', col]].set_index('COLUMN_NM').plot.bar(title=col)
```

The issues with your code were:

- `grid[('COLUMN_NM', 'DISTINCT_COUNT')]` won't work because you are using a tuple, instead of `[(...)]` you want `[[...]]` to select a subset of columns
- You also want to set the column by which you want your bars grouped (`COLUMN_NM`) as the index

Comment: thank you!  I'll set this as answered but I just realized this puts the column names along the bottom, which would look messy if there are lots of them.  I actually want them in a box in the upper right.  That would look cleaner, then just a label at the bottom that reads 'Columns'.  Any tips on that? If not I can mess around with it.  Thanks again